# How do I correctly make a C# property of data type varchar?

Tags: c#, syntax, types, varchar

We are making a ASP.NET application and made the database first.  We are trying to add our User table instead of using the default database.  I want to add the properties, such as UserID which is of the data type varchar and of variable length (30).  No matter how I enter it, the syntax is incorrect.

I have tried:
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public varchar (30) UserId { get; set; }
    public varchar Email (30) { get; set; }
    public varchar Password (30) { get; set; }

Do I have to change everything in the database to match the code, or if I use string in the code, can I leave it varchar in the database?

and it says `the symbol varchar cannot be resoved.`

Please help.

Comment: `varchar` is a **SQL** datatype - not C# / .NET. In C#, use a `string`

Comment: In the database type Email is of type varchar (30), but in C# it won't be accepted.  Would that be a datatype mismatch if I use a string and what about the variable length.  The actual code is: public varchar (30) Email {get; set;}

Comment: public int UserID { get; set; }

Answer (score 2):

`varchar` is a SQL Server data type, you need to use the .NET's `string` type in your C# code. The code below is valid of any size of `varchar` data:

```
public string Email {get; set;}
```

You can check [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx) for other SQL Server data types and their .NET equilavents.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested in the comments, use a `string` which is the c# equivalent of the SQL data type `varchar`